# The page is not scrolling all the way to the bottom in html and css

Tags: html, css

I have created a registration form using html and css. Earlier there were only 7 input fields and since I wanted 2 more input fields I added 2 more textboxes to enter the username and password.

When it had only seven textboxes it showed me the submit button. but after I added the additional textboxes it wont show me the registration button although I scroll down

here I didn't include the php code since it doesn't have any problem

here's the css code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
 background-position: center;
    background-blend-mode: soft-light;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    
}

#form1
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.regform
{
 
  width: 500px;
    height: 880px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 70px 30px;
    
 
 
}

.regform p
{
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
 
}

.regform input[type="text"],[type="datetime-local"] ,[type="date"],[type="Password"]{
 
  width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#regbt{
 
 width: 85%;
 position: fixed;
 border: none;
    outline: none;
 
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
 margin:9px 0;
 
}

#regbt:hover{
 
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #000;
 
}
```

here's the html code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style6.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registration </title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- regform -->
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
  <div class="regform">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Student ID:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuid" class="textfield"  readonly><br><!-- Auto incremented in table-->

   <p><label for="textfield">Student Name:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuname" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your full name" required><br>

 <p><label for="textfield">User Name:</label></p>
     <input type="text" name="stu_uname" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your username" required><br>


 <p><label for="textfield">Password:</label></p>
     <input type="Password" name="stu_pass" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your Password" required><br>


   <p><label for="textfield">NIC or Passport No.:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stunic" class="textfield" placeholder="enter your NIC number or Passport number" required><br>

   <p> <label for="textfield">Address:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuaddress" class="textfield" placeholder="enter your address" required><br> 
   <table width="200">
     <tr>
       <td><p>Gender:</p><label>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="radio" id="Gender_0" required>
         Male</label></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label>
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="radio" id="Gender_1" required>
         Female</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <br>
    
 <p><label> D.O.B:</label></p>
      <input type="date"  name="dob" required><br>

       <p> <label for="textfield">Registration Number:</label></p>
      <input type="text" name="sturegno" class="textfield" required ><br>
<!-- Auto incremented in the table-->


  <p><label>Registration Date:</label></p><input name="regdate" type="datetime-local" required><br>

  <input type="submit" name="regbt1" id="regbt" value="Register">
   </div>
  
  </form>
  

</body>
</html>
```

please ignore any errors that I have done when posting the question.

Comment: Is it because your `.regform` has a fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a fixed height size for your `.regform`

update it as following:

```
.regform {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    [...]
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
 background-position: center;
    background-blend-mode: soft-light;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    
}

#form1
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.regform
{
 
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 70px 30px;
    
 
 
}

.regform p
{
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
 
}

.regform input[type="text"],[type="datetime-local"] ,[type="date"],[type="Password"]{
 
  width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#regbt{
 
 width: 85%;
 position: fixed;
 border: none;
    outline: none;
 
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
 margin:9px 0;
 
}

#regbt:hover{
 
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #000;
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style6.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registration </title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- regform -->
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
  <div class="regform">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Student ID:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuid" class="textfield"  readonly><br><!-- Auto incremented in table-->

   <p><label for="textfield">Student Name:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuname" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your full name" required><br>

 <p><label for="textfield">User Name:</label></p>
     <input type="text" name="stu_uname" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your username" required><br>


 <p><label for="textfield">Password:</label></p>
     <input type="Password" name="stu_pass" class="textfield" placeholder="Enter your Password" required><br>


   <p><label for="textfield">NIC or Passport No.:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stunic" class="textfield" placeholder="enter your NIC number or Passport number" required><br>

   <p> <label for="textfield">Address:</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="stuaddress" class="textfield" placeholder="enter your address" required><br> 
   <table width="200">
     <tr>
       <td><p>Gender:</p><label>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="radio" id="Gender_0" required>
         Male</label></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label>
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="radio" id="Gender_1" required>
         Female</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <br>
    
 <p><label> D.O.B:</label></p>
      <input type="date"  name="dob" required><br>

       <p> <label for="textfield">Registration Number:</label></p>
      <input type="text" name="sturegno" class="textfield" required ><br>
<!-- Auto incremented in the table-->


  <p><label>Registration Date:</label></p><input name="regdate" type="datetime-local" required><br>

  <input type="submit" name="regbt1" id="regbt" value="Register">
   </div>
  
  </form>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having no trouble seeing your register button, are you sure it is not a cache problem? Maybe press ctrl + f5.